# Calendar in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, calendar

Please let me know if this question is posted in the wrong place of Stack - I will make sure to delete this and re-write a new post in the correct place. As of now, I saw similar questions around here and deemed this acceptable as well.

So, I am wondering what should I use in order to create a view with a calendar on the whole page that has dates highlighted depending on the database dates. For example, in the database, I have the following table:

[image]

Therefore, as I said - in the calendar view, there should be a huge calendar with the `StartDate` and `EndDate` highlighted with certain colors, also stating the `Name` of the Release.

How could this be possible? I am pretty new to this stuff so I am looking for some hints on how I should approach this issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What calendar are you using? The HTML5 Calendar? jQuery UI calendar or something else?

Comment: At this point I don't use any - I am looking for advice on which could be better for a simple task such as this.

Comment: Are you using the calendar as a "date picker" or just for display purposes?

Comment: Just for display purposes.

Comment: @Questieme - you could build a html table yourself, or use something like -> https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Have added an answer with a jQuery UI calendar example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It think you posted this at the proper spot. Your tags look great.

If you are familiar with JavaScript and ASP.Net Core Web APIs I would recommend [Full Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/).

1. Add a controller to your ASP.Net Core project in the Controllers folder.
2. Add Full Calendar to your page.  ([Read this.](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started))
3. Full Calendar will call your API for the event data. (reference the Full Calendar docs for the return JSON format)

Wishing you the best.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of calendar I was looking for. Thank you very much for helping out.

Comment: Splendid! Glad I could help.

Comment: This is not a package I was aware of, but looks really good and something I will play with in the future and is definitely more suited to the question than my answer. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend going for a jQuery UI approach. You can customise it freely (see their documentation)

You can use AJAX/jQuery or something to get the dates from the database via a method in your controller. Then display the calendar in a div.

Here's a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhpc7zt2/1/

```
var events = [ 
{ Title: "Birthday", Date: new Date("12/12/2019") }, 
{ Title: "Christmas", Date: new Date("12/25/2019") }, 
{ Title: "Boxing Day", Date: new Date("12/26/2019") }
];

$("#calendar").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var result = [true, '', null];
    var tooltip = "";
    var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
        if (event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
        tooltip = event.Title;
        return true;
      }
    });

    if (matching.length > 0) {
        result = [true, 'event', tooltip];
    }
    return result;
}
});
```

To get the JSON from the controller:

```
var events;    
$.getJSON('dateController/read', null, function(output) {
    events = output;
}
```

Then your controller action would be something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult read()
{
    //Database call to read dates and convert them to JSON object...

    List<SelectedDates> highlightDates = new List<SelectedDates>();
        highlightDates.Add(new SelectedDates { Date = new DateTime(2019, 12, 
    1), Title = "Birthday" });

    return Json(highlightDates);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am sorry I couldn't answer this faster - it was due to holidays. I will test it out, see how it goes and come back if I have any other questions.